# Как реализовать регулярную отправку сообщения в определённое время используя библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, telebot

Пишу бота для telegram используя библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI.Хочу реализовать ежедневную отправку сообщения в определённое время.Сообщение будет содержать информацию о сегодняшним празднике.
*Использовал beautifulsoup4

```
URL = 'https://calend.ru/day/'

source = requests.get(URL)
main_text = source.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_text)

mainL = soup.find('li', {'class': 'full'})
holiday = mainL.find('span', {'class': 'caption days_section'})
name = holiday.find('a').text

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Сегодня " + str(name))
```

Но как реализовать отправку этого сообщения регулярно?*В моём случае в 8:00 утра.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких целей прекрасно подойдёт модуль [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/).

***Пример:***

```py
import schedule
import time

def job():
    ...


schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

А для того чтобы не прерывать выполнение основной программы, можно запустить цикл проверки в отдельном потоке или процессе с помощью стандартных библиотек [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) и [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) соответственно.