# Нужно чтобы бот вызвал функцию в определенное время каждый день, как это реализовать? Библиотека - pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Может есть какой то декоратор или библиотека для таких целей, я пробовал реализовать через потоки но получилось плохо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087059/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-long-polling-%d0%b8-schedule/1087061#1087061

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) почитай, хорошая либа для расписания.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать регулярную отправку сообщения в определённое время используя библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105879/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-